# Bias-variance decomposition for time series

Tags: time-series, bias-variance-tradeoff

Suppose you have a time series $y_t$. What is the bias-variance decomposition of

$$E[[y_{t+1} - \hat{y}_{t+1}]^2|y_1, \dots, y_t] $$

where $\hat{y}_{t+1}$ is some forecast of $y_t$.

I tried to prove that it is equivalent to

$$Var[y_{t+1} - \hat{y}_{t+1}|y_1, \dots, y_t] + [E[y_{t+1}|y_1, \dots, y_t] - E_{y_1:y_t}[\hat{y}_{t+1}]]^2$$

where $E_{y_1:y_t}$ denotes that the expectation is taken over $y_1, \dots, y_t$.

I was able to get the first two terms but there is a cross-product term that I can't see is equivalent to zero.